# Square root of 6 proof rationality

Tags: rational-numbers

I was proving $\sqrt 6 \notin \Bbb Q$, by assuming its negation and stating that: $\exists (p,q) \in \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z^*/ \gcd(p,q) = 1$, and $\sqrt 6 = (p/q)$.

$\implies p^2 = 2 \times 3q^2 \implies \exists k \in \Bbb Z; p = 2k \implies 2k^2 = 3q^2$ and found two possible cases, either $q$ is even or odd, if even we get contradiction that $\gcd(p, q) \neq 1$, if odd we get contradiction that $2k^2 = 3q^2$.

Is it a right path for reasoning it?

Comment: Is the $k$ a typo?  What is $p, k$ and $q$?  Why is $q$ being even a condradiction with $\gcd(p,q) = 1$?  And why is $2k^2 = 3q^2$ a contradiction?  You just said $2k^2 = 3q^2$ so that isn't a contradiction?  You are on the right track but you haven't explained any of your arguments.

Comment: Why is $q$ even a contradiction?  What if $k$ or $p$ (whats the difference) is odd?

Comment: I rearranged it!

Answer (score 2):

How about a proof by descent?

First show that $2^2<6<3^2$.  Then if $\sqrt{6}$ is to be rational it must have a form $p/q$ where $p,q\in \mathbb{Z}, q>0, 2q<p<3q$.  By simple algebra the square root is also equal to $6q/p$, thus

$p/q=6q/p\text{.....Eq. 1}$.

Now if $a/b=c/d$ then also

$a/b=(ma+nc)/(mb+nd)$

for any coefficients $m,n$ where the denominator is nonzero.  In particular, Eq. 1 implies

$p/q=(3p-6q)/(3q-p)\text{.....Eq. 2}$

where we already have $2q<p<3q$ and thus $0<3q-p<q$.  So the proposed rational fraction $p/q$ must be equal to an alternative rational fraction with a smaller positive denominator.  This causes an infinite descent contradiction forcing the assumption of a rational value to be false.

We can form a similar proof for the square root of *any* natural number that is *not a squared integer*.  "Not a squared integer" is needed because the square root must be strictly between two adjacent integers to obtain a descent of positive denominators.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $\sqrt{6} = {a \over b}$ with $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ . This implies

$$2 \cdot 3 b^2 = a^2$$

Use the fundamental theorem of algebra to decompose both sides into a unique prime factorization.  There are an even number of factors of $2$ on the rhs and an odd number of factors of $2$ on the lhs... a contradition.  Same for factors of $3$.

Thus $\sqrt{6} \neq {a \over b}$, i.e., is irrational.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to reach it without prime factorisation. A second look?

Comment: You are considering the *value* of the rhs and lhs of the equation.  I am instead looking at the *number of prime factors*.  Frankly, I think that is so much more elegant... but I suppose this is a matter of taste.  Mine applies to $\sqrt{5/3}$ whereas yours doesn't... at least not as directly.

Comment: Our professor used the value way, so I am following his steps for this, though, thanks!

Comment: Show him/her the better way!  And stand out as a student!

Comment: Well, that doesn t apply in Morocco. Pray for me I win visa lottery so I can join a better faculty in the US :)

Comment: Well, prayer doesn't work... never has, never will.  (Sorry to have to tell you.)  But hard study and dedication can work!

Comment: Thanks, that s what my God actually demands for me as a muslim :)

Comment: @J.Moh:  Oh too bad.  Sorry to hear it.

Comment: Oh No, God demands hard work and dedication, even perfection in a Hadith: if one of you is to do a work, one has to perfect it! That doesn't go against the philosophy of prayer in Islam :)

Comment: Oh I know the Quran and Hadith very well indeed, and know the demands that it places upon you.  It is, though, a simple fact—proven innumerable times—that prayer does not work... never has, never will.  But I know I cannot convince you of this fact.  I'll let you, as a budding mathematician/scientist, look for *objective* evidence.  (You'll never find it.) . Bye bye.  Over and out.

Comment: Okey :) Though you ll stay responding to my questions if you come about one haha :)

Comment: I didn t know you re a well establish academic, I am honored to talk to you David :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll play more generally
and see what happens.

Suppose
$\sqrt{m}
=\dfrac{u}{v}
$
where
$m = \prod_{p \in P} p^{m_i},
u = \prod_{p \in P} p^{u_i},
v = \prod_{p \in P} p^{v_i}
$.

Then
$\prod_{p \in P} p^{m_i}
=\dfrac{u^2}{v^2}
=\dfrac{ \prod_{p \in P} p^{2u_i}}{\prod_{p \in P} p^{2v_i}}
$
so
$\prod_{p \in P} p^{m_i}\prod_{p \in P} p^{2v_i}
=\prod_{p \in P} p^{2u_i}
$
or
$\prod_{p \in P} p^{m_i+2v_i}
=\prod_{p \in P} p^{2u_i}
$.

By unique factorization,
$m_i+2v_i
=2u_i
$,
so
$m_i
=2u_i-2v_i
=2(u_i-v_i)
$.

Therefore
$m
=\prod_{p \in P} p^{m_i}
=\prod_{p \in P} p^{2(u_i-v_i)}
=\left(\prod_{p \in P} p^{u_i-v_i}\right)^2
$
so $m$ is a perfect square.

Therefore
the square root of an integer
is rational
only if
it is a square.

I'll now try to generalize this
to $k$-th roots,
with as much cut-and-paste
as possible.

Suppose
$\sqrt[k]{m}
=\dfrac{u}{v}
$
where
$m = \prod_{p \in P} p^{m_i},
u = \prod_{p \in P} p^{u_i},
v = \prod_{p \in P} p^{v_i}
$.

Then
$\prod_{p \in P} p^{m_i}
=\dfrac{u^k}{v^k}
=\dfrac{ \prod_{p \in P} p^{ku_i}}{\prod_{p \in P} p^{kv_i}}
$
so
$\prod_{p \in P} p^{m_i}\prod_{p \in P} p^{kv_i}
=\prod_{p \in P} p^{ku_i}
$
or
$\prod_{p \in P} p^{m_i+kv_i}
=\prod_{p \in P} p^{ku_i}
$.

By unique factorization,
$m_i+kv_i
=ku_i
$,
so
$m_i
=ku_i-kv_i
=k(u_i-v_i)
$.

Therefore
$m
=\prod_{p \in P} p^{m_i}
=\prod_{p \in P} p^{k(u_i-v_i)}
=\left(\prod_{p \in P} p^{u_i-v_i}\right)^k
$
so $m$ is a perfect $k$-th power.

Therefore
the $k$-th root of an integer
is rational
only if
it is a $k$-th power.

Answer (score 0):

When you get $2p^2 = 3q^2$ that means that $2|q^2$ so $2|q$ and that $3|p^2$ so $3|p$.

Then if you replace $p = 3p'$ for some integer $p'$ and $q=2q'$ for some integer $q'$ you get

$2(3p')^2 = 3(2q')^2$

$18p'^2 = 12q'^2$

$3p'^3 = 2q'^2$.

Can you finish from there?

This assumes you know Euclid's lemma that 1) prime numbers exist and 2) if $p$ is prime and $p|a*b$ then either $p|a$ or $p|b$ (or both).

Comment: I tried to reach it without prime factorisation, can you have a second look?